# Why do I get this error trying to build Komparator from source?

Tags: 11.10, package-management, install-from-source

I downloaded **Komparator** source from [this page](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?action=content&content=116039). The INSTALL file in the source say the following:

```
Unpack komparator4-xxx.tar.bz2, and open a shell inside this directory

mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix` ..
make
sudo make install
```

I unpacked the file, make the directory, entered this, but when I have tried to `cmake` (sentence Nº3) the terminal print the following errors disabling me to *make & install*:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:98 (MESSAGE):
  ERROR: cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake not found in
  /home/lucio/.kde/share/apps;/usr/share/kde4/apps
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What does this errors mean and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INSTALL` file says you need the following:

```
Install required packages: gettext, cmake, g++, kde and qt development packages
(including qt3support and kde4's kde3 compatibility libraries)
```

From the error, it appears you are missing `kdelibs5` and/or `kdevplatform5-libs`, but to be safe I would install the `kdebase-workspace-dev` metapackage. In short, to successfully compile this program, run the following in Konsole:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential kdebase-workspace-dev gettext libkde3support4 libqt4-qt3support
```

---

After that, `cmake`completes successfully:

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~/komparator4-0.7/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix` ..
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.1 (using /usr/bin/qmake)
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found KDE 4.8 include dir: /usr/include
-- Found KDE 4.8 library dir: /usr/lib
-- Found the KDE4 kconfig_compiler preprocessor: /usr/bin/kconfig_compiler
-- Found automoc4: /usr/bin/automoc4
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/kubuntu/komparator4-0.7/build
```

Comment: The 'kdebase-workspace-dev' package was not in my system, I installed it and now I could install Komparator.