# Docbook errors building Komparator from source

Tags: 11.10, install-from-source, make

I'm trying to install [Komparator4](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=116039) **v0.8** from the terminal of **Ubuntu 11.10**. I entered this command and work fine:

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix` ..
```

But when I enter `make` I get [this output whit error messages](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1128080/).

I installed this program with this method twice previously and I had no problems.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code is written perfectly. Each char is necessary.

Comment: Which OS (Kubuntu?), version (11.10?) and Komparator4 version (0.8 is available...)

Comment: Have you reviewed the issues/comments in http://askubuntu.com/questions/160222/why-do-get-this-error-trying-to-build-komparator-from-source ? ***Are you missing any of the required packages?***

Comment: @david6 Yes, I reviewed that question and I installed all the packages without problem. After that I installed the app without problems but this time is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors you get, e.g.:

```
index.docbook:1054: parser error : Entity 'install.compile.documentation' not defined
```

is the exact behavior displayed by an old [serious bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=642719) in Komparator, which was *fixed* in late 2011 in Komparator 0.6.

If you are still getting this error, you should report it as a bug to the Komparator dev-team.

#### Temporary Alternative: build without documentation

For now, if you wish to build the package and can just refer to the online documentation, here's how:

- In the top level folder, edit `CMakelists.txt` and in front of line 38, `add_subdirectory(doc)`, add a `#`, i.e. `#add_subdirectory(doc)`.
- Save, exit, and `cd build && cmake .....`
- This should build the package successfully.

---

I was able to successfully build [Komparator 4 0.7](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1153958) and [Komparator 4 0.8](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1153953/) on an up-to-date Kubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I updated my question with my OS and version of K. I also build Komparator4 v0.7 without problems but a couple of days later I uninstalled it and when I tried again (with the same version) this errors appear.

Comment: Added comment to **62483**

Comment: I updated the system, I downloaded and builded Komparator but nothing happens. I still get the same output with errors.

Comment: @Lucio: please see edited answer - I found an old bug in Komparator exactly similar to your problem, but they say it was fixed. I have added an alternative method to successfully build the package.

Comment: @izx I don't know how you do, but you do. It works. Thanks for your time!